# Heap allocation and Initialisation of a base class in the initializer list of its derived class’ constructor

Tags: c++, heap-memory, delete-operator, derived-class

```
class Base
{
int n;
public:
    Base(int n)
        : n(n)
    {}
       ...
}

class Derived : Base
{
public:
    Derived(int n)
        : Base(n)
    {}
}

void function()
{
    Derived* obj  = new Derived(10);

       ...

    delete obj;
}
```

I have a similar situation as with the above code, where **Derived** is just a wrapper of **Base**. To access the object in **function** I’m using a **Derived** pointer on purpose. My understanding is that the whole object it’s allocated on the heap, including the **Base** part and that delete reclaims all the memory, even if I use a **Derived** pointer and **Base** is not polymorphic. Is this correct or there is something more to it ?

Thanks

Comment: Correct. The other cases would be described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498332/does-delete-work-properly-with-polymorphism?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: What's the point of allocating the object on the heap? Unless there is a good reason (there are some) you are best off to use a value of the object on the stack (and if it goes on the heap, use a smart pointer, most likely `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` to get it cleaned up).

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: I don't like this question you pointed at as duplicate: primarily, the code is full of undefined behaviour (manually explicitly destroying an object on the stack results in double destruction).

Comment: @Captain Giraffe It's not a duplicate as the questions pointed out by you are explicitly using base pointer to access the object.

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl what's the point ? Getting a deep knowledge of c++ and not just using other peoples ideas without knowing what's in it.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe Please, put your first comment as answer so that I can accept it and close the question. Thanks.